# Streaming WCF - 400 Bad Request

Tags: .net, wcf, streaming, http-status-code-400

I have been circling around setting up a Streaming service for the last couple days and everytime I come back to the task I keep hitting the same wall of 400 Bad Request. I have searched a number of posts here and out on the web and it seems like this is a frequent issue but each situation is different. Below is the current state of my bindings setup - I feel like this has to be something small I am overlooking.

Information from WCF profiler:

- When the service is called, a Warning is thrown stating "Configuration Evaluation context not found."
- The next entry states "No matching service tag was found. Default endpoints added."

This leads me to believe that whatever I have set up is not being applied to the service and, hence, throw the Bad Request error because it is using the ~64kb default which my stream exceeds.

```
      <!-- Services Config -->
        <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097150" executionTimeout="7200"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />    
        </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>        
          <binding name="StreamingService"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" >
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
            <security mode="None">
            </security>
          </binding>        
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="StreamingService" behaviorConfiguration="StreamingServiceBehavior">
          <endpoint address="http://localhost:50577/StreamingContent.svc"
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamingService"
         contract="IStreamingContent" name="BasicHttpBinding_IStreamingContent" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

       <!-- Web Server Config -->
        <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IStreamingContent" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
           maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>    
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:50577/StreamingService.svc"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IStreamingService"
            contract="StreamingService.IStreamingService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IStreamingService" />
        </client>
```

Any fresh perspectives would certainly help.

**EDIT**: I updated the configurations above after taking the advice below but I am still getting the same issue in the profiler where no matching  tag is found, only this time I *believe* my setup is correct..... obviously not because it would work now wouldn't it, eh?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I think that one of the reasons of your issue is that you configuring an endpoint using `<client>` section on the server side when in fact you should use `<services>` section to configure your service endpoint. Please see an example of the server config file for streaming here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/streaming-in-wcf/

Be really careful with your config files this is where most problems come in WCF

Comment: Sigh - yup, I think this has me headed in the right direction. Having it setup in the client section seemed wrong to me. Will get this worked in and let you know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: While I felt this was going to right the ship, something is still arye.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

I got the "No matching  tag was found. Default endpoints added."

My xml was fine.  (after I spent an hour trying to find malformed xml).

The issue for me was I had changed the namespace of my concrete-service class.

The key is this.

In the .svc file, there is a some markup

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyCompany.MyNamespace.MyConcreteService" %>
```

This has to be the FULLY qualified name of the .cs class.

AND

your service model xml has to have the fully qualfied name as well.

```
  <service name="MyCompany.MyNamespace.MyConcreteService"
           behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior"
           >

        <!-- 
        Whole bunch of other stuff not shown here
        -->

  </service>
```

The above would mimic the class

```
namespace MyCompany.MyNamespace
{
    public class MyConcreteService : IMyService
    {
    }
}
```

Make sure you have the CORRECT fully qualified name AND they are copied to the .svc file correctly AND the  xml correctly.

I got the answer from here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3bb9b3ad-8fc4-40a6-9bb8-fb34f9011d39/bad-request-error-when-uploading-file-to-server?forum=wcf

***It's possible that the  element is not being recognized by WCF. The value of the "name" attribute in the  element must be the fully-qualified name of the service class - since you're using IIS to host the service, it needs to be the same value as the "Service" attribute in the @ServiceHost tag in the .svc file.***